# .Net MAUI - Github dependency

Tags: c#, github, xamarin, maui

I have a blank .Net MAUI App that im planning to use, for simplicity sake, on Android only at the moment. I am trying to use a Github hosted service, namely Zettle by PayPal. Their documentation for using their Android SDK is here:

https://developer.zettle.com/docs/android-sdk/installation-and-configuration

"The Zettle Payment SDK for Android is available as packages from the GitHub package hosting service. To include the Android SDK in your project, you need to add a dependency to the package service, using your GitHub Token."

I have been trying to research how to include this in a MAUI Application, but I havent found anything relevant. Does anyone have any experience to point me in the right direction in getting a Github Package included in a MAUI or XAMARIN App?

I have looked at 'Microsoft Dependency Injection' but I dont believe this will work under these circumstances.

Comment: I should add, there is no Nuget package for this.

Comment: You would (I assume) need to download the actual Android library/JAR and then create a binding library for it